# Spring boot validator not setting the error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, spring-mvc

I'm building a library management system with thymeleaf and spring boot. I'm having some troubles with validating my wrapper class.

When adding a book you can add up to 3 authors so I made a wrapper class:

```
package com.springBoot.Bibliotheek.controller;

import java.util.List;

import com.springBoot.Bibliotheek.model.Author;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class FormAuthorsWrapper {
    private List<Author> authorsWrapper;
    private String errorMessage;

}
```

Then I wrote a custom validator to check if any of the 3 authors has been filled in:

```
package com.springBoot.Bibliotheek.validator;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import com.springBoot.Bibliotheek.controller.FormAuthorsWrapper;
import com.springBoot.Bibliotheek.model.Author;

import io.micrometer.common.util.StringUtils;

public class FormAuthorsWrapperValidation implements Validator{
    
    
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return FormAuthorsWrapper.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        FormAuthorsWrapper wrapper = (FormAuthorsWrapper) target;
        List<Author> authors = wrapper.getAuthorsWrapper();
        
        List<Author> validAuthors = authors.stream()
                .filter(this::isAuthorValid)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        
        if(validAuthors.isEmpty()) {
            errors.rejectValue("errorMessage", "Test", "Test");

        } else {
            wrapper.setAuthorsWrapper(validAuthors);
        }
    }
    
    private boolean isAuthorValid(Author author) {
        String firstname = author.getFirstname();
        String lastname = author.getLastname();
        return !StringUtils.isEmpty(firstname) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(lastname);
    }

}
```

The rejectValue method is called but the errorMessage field is not being set properly. Here is the controller:

```
    @PostMapping(path ="/add")
    public String postAddBookForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute Book book,BindingResult bindingResultBook,@ModelAttribute FormAuthorsWrapper wrapper,BindingResult bindingResultWrapper,
            @ModelAttribute FormLocationsWrapper locationsWrapper,Model model) {
            isbnValidator.validate(book, bindingResultBook);
            formAuthorsWrapperValidation.validate(wrapper, bindingResultWrapper);
    
            System.out.println(bindingResultWrapper.getModel());
            
        if(bindingResultBook.hasErrors() || bindingResultWrapper.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("book", book);
            model.addAttribute("authors", wrapper);
            model.addAttribute("locations", locationsWrapper);
            
            System.out.print(bindingResultWrapper.getFieldError());
            
            System.out.println(bindingResultWrapper.getAllErrors());
            
            return "addBook";
        }
        
        book.getAuthors().addAll(wrapper.getAuthorsWrapper());
        book.setImgUrl(
                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d1/Image_not_available.png/640px-Image_not_available.png"); //Random URL for now. Will add image upload later.

        Book addedBook = bookService.addBook(book);

        locationService.addLocationsForBook(locationsWrapper.getLocationsWrapper(), addedBook);

        return "redirect:/books";
    }
```

The isbn validator is working fine. What I get from the prints in console is this:

```
{formAuthorsWrapper=FormAuthorsWrapper(authorsWrapper=[Author(firstname=, lastname=), Author(firstname=, lastname=), Author(firstname=, lastname=)], errorMessage=null), org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.formAuthorsWrapper=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'formAuthorsWrapper' on field 'errorMessage': rejected value [null]; codes [Test.formAuthorsWrapper.errorMessage,Test.errorMessage,Test.java.lang.String,Test]; arguments []; default message [Test]}
```

What seems weird to me is that errorMessage = null, but the second println says that there is an error on field errorMessage.

This is how I try to access the error in thymeleaf:

```
            <div th:object="${authors}">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"
                        th:text="#{addBookpage.author} + ' 1*'"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{authorsWrapper[0].firstname}"
                            class="form-control-plaintext border border-secondary text-secondary ps-2 rounded"
                            id="author1-firstname"
                            th:placeholder="#{addBookpage.authorFistName}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{authorsWrapper[0].lastname}"
                            class="form-control-plaintext border border-secondary text-secondary ps-2 rounded"
                            id="author1-lastname"
                            th:placeholder="#{addBookpage.authorLastName}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"
                        th:text="#{addBookpage.author} + ' 2'"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{authorsWrapper[1].firstname}"
                            class="form-control-plaintext border border-secondary text-secondary ps-2 rounded"
                            id="author2-firstname"
                            th:placeholder="#{addBookpage.authorFistName}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{authorsWrapper[1].lastname}"
                            class="form-control-plaintext border border-secondary text-secondary ps-2 rounded"
                            id="author2-lastname"
                            th:placeholder="#{addBookpage.authorLastName}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"
                        th:text="#{addBookpage.author} + ' 3'"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{authorsWrapper[2].firstname}"
                            class="form-control-plaintext border border-secondary text-secondary ps-2 rounded"
                            id="author3-firstname"
                            th:placeholder="#{addBookpage.authorFistName}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{authorsWrapper[2].lastname}"
                            class="form-control-plaintext border border-secondary text-secondary ps-2 rounded"
                            id="author3-lastname"
                            th:placeholder="#{addBookpage.authorLastName}">
                        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('errorMessage')}" class="error" th:errors="*{errorMessage}"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The if statement in span always evaluates to false. What am I doing wrong?